# Chrome Developer Console hiding Errors

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I think in this case, a picture will be worth a thousand words.  I really have no idea why this is happening, but the error is in my code, and nothing I have tried will allow me to see.  Nothing is blackboxed.  Nothing is filtered out.  The things that look greyed out like they are disabled, are disabled.  I cannot edit them.  Unchecking "Group Similar" has no effect.

[image: Screenshot]

You can see where I point to the red lines, it looks like they are indicative a hidden error message here.

I am using `Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.  Did I do this somehow?  Is this a bug maybe?  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Click on the gear icon on the right. Uncheck "Hide network".

Comment: Already unchecked.

Comment: Try a different version of Chrome e.g. Canary.

Comment: @wOxxOm - That's really good advice.  I solved the bug, but if it happens again, this is probably the first place I'll go.

Answer (score -2):

go to console and press f1 to go to setting. At the end of page you get link to restore setting and reload.